# Python3 Multithreading with 2 loops and if Condition

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a script that goes through a list of urls and a list of keywords, if it finds a keyword in the response, it should stop trying more keywords against the same url, and should continue with other urls, I could apply this logic on a single thread script, but when I tried multithreading, it didn't stop and continued testing all keywords even if a keyword is already found.

```
import concurrent.futures
import requests

urls = ['http://url1/search.html?keyword=','http://url2/search.html?keyword=','http://url3/search.html?keyword=']

keywords = ['keyword1','keyword2','keyword3','keyword4','keyword5','keyword6','keyword7','keyword8']
result = {}

# Add new key,value in result dictionary for every url in the list
for n, val in enumerate(urls):
    globals()["found%d" % n] = val
    result.update({val: []})


def searcher(url,keyword):
    if len(result[url]) == 0: # check if any keyword is already found
        req = requests.get(url + keyword, verify=False)
        if keyword in req.text:
            print(keyword + ' found in ' + url)
            result.setdefault(url).append(keyword)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:

     res = [executor.submit(searcher, url, keyword)  for url in urls for keyword in keywords]


print(result)
```

expected result:

```
{'http://url1/search.html?keyword=': ['keyword8'], 'http://url2/search.html?keyword=': ['keyword1'], 'http://url3/search.html?keyword=': ['keyword2']}
```

Script result:

```
{'http://url1/search.html?keyword=': ['keyword8', 'keyword2', 'keyword1', 'keyword3', 'keyword4', 'keyword5', 'keyword6', 'keyword7'], 'http://url2/search.html?keyword=': ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3', 'keyword5', 'keyword6', 'keyword4', 'keyword7', 'keyword8'], 'http://url3/search.html?keyword=': ['keyword1', 'keyword4', 'keyword3', 'keyword2', 'keyword6', 'keyword7', 'keyword5', 'keyword8']}
```

What I'm thinking of is (but don't know how):
1- create a pool of threads for each url that iterates all keywords
2- if a keyword is found, clear the url threads pool
3- control all threads for all urls so that they don't exceed like 50 concurrent threads in total (for large urls lists)

Comment: This is terrible: `globals()["found%d" % n] = val`. Use a list instead.

Comment: Am a beginner, this the way that I could find to create a dictionary of a variable length, that will be created depending on the urls count that is read from a file (not hardcoded urls like in my example). Also I need it a dictionary not a list to save found keywords in front of every url